# Fake.Deploy Running custom Windows Service locks deployment files and thus updates

Tags: f#, windows-services, f#-fake

I'd like to deploy some Windows Services using FAKE. 
After deploying the package using a FAKE build script I install the services using the after deployment build script (*.fsx).

This is all working great except that as soon as the service is started, the files become locked. This prohibits any further (update) deployments.

Is it somehow possible to stop the service before FAKE.Deploy tries to overwrite the files?

Comment: I think, the easiest solution is to wrap the fake build in a batch command and stop the service from the batch command before running the deploy script.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using Fake.Deploy and thus deploy using nuget packages, created by FAKE to a remote VM. Fake.Deploy is listening on that VM, extracts the received nuget packages and then executes the deployment script (*.fsx) that is supplied with the package. I'd like to stop the service before it extracts the package.

Comment: Then you might have a look at this: http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper.html. Seems there is an api for that use case.

Comment: So far that seems like the best idea, but that would mean I have to shutdown the service remote. Unless I deploy an (almost) empty package to the VM that contains a deployment script that shutsdown the services prior to deploying them. Seems like an 'okay' solution to me, although I'd rather like to have a pre-deployment script that Fake.Deploy executes that stops the service.

Comment: Just copy service to new directory and install from there. https://gist.github.com/sergey-tihon/419589f96f8de1193010

Comment: @SergeyTihon Doh, of course. Thanks, if you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do not install your service from directory where FAKE unzip it.
Do it like this:

1. Check that target directory is exist. Create it if it is not
2. Check if service is installed and uninstall in this case
3. Clean target directory (to be sure that everything is removed)
4. Copy files of new version
5. Install new version of service in target directory

Deployment script from my project:

```
#r @"c:\Project\FAKE.Deploy\bin\FAKE\tools\FakeLib.dll"

open Fake
open System
open System.IO

let targetDirectory = @"c:\Project\Service"
let runScript file =
    if File.Exists file then
        let result, messages =
            ExecProcessRedirected
                (fun info ->
                    info.FileName <- file
                    info.WorkingDirectory <- targetDirectory)
                (TimeSpan.FromMinutes 10.0)
        for msg in messages do
            (if msg.IsError then traceError else traceImportant) msg.Message

        if not result then
            failwithf "MyProc.exe returned with a non-zero exit code"
    else
        traceImportant <| sprintf "File %s is not found" file

// *** Define Targets ***

Target "EnsureDirectory" (fun () ->
    trace <| sprintf " --- Ensure that directory '%s' is exist --- " targetDirectory
    CreateDir targetDirectory
)

Target "UninstallService" (fun () ->
    trace " --- Uninstall service --- "
    targetDirectory @@ "uninstall.bat"
    |> runScript
)

Target "CleanDirectory" (fun () ->
    trace " --- Clean target directory --- "
    CleanDir targetDirectory
)

Target "CopyFiles" (fun () ->
    trace " --- Copy new files --- "
    XCopy (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ @@ "content") targetDirectory
)

Target "InstallService" (fun () ->
    trace " --- Install service --- "
    targetDirectory @@ "install.bat"
    |> runScript
)

Target "Deploy" DoNothing

// *** Define Dependencies ***
"EnsureDirectory"
  ==> "UninstallService"
  ==> "CleanDirectory"
  ==> "CopyFiles"
  ==> "InstallService"
  ==> "Deploy"

// *** Start Build ***
RunParameterTargetOrDefault "target" "Deploy"
```

Comment: For those wondering, this is FAKE4 - it does need some adjustments to be usable in FAKE5